# Asset pipeline encoding problems (UTF-8 vs. ASCII-8BIT) with external gem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to create a gem that wraps d3.js, Source can be found at https://github.com/iblue/d3-rails

So when I include this gem in my Gemfile

```
gem "d3-rails", :git => "git://github.com/iblue/d3-rails.git"
```

And when I include the javascript in my application.js:

```
//=require d3
```

Then my asset compilation fails and my compiled application.js just contains

```
throw Error("Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT")
```

I am using Rails 3.1.3 and ruby-1.9.3-p125. jQuery uses exactly the same gem structure and it works. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**:

I also saw this question: [Ruby 1.9 throwing javascript encoding error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9116752/ruby-1-9-throwing-javascript-encoding-error). This does not apply here, my file is valid UTF-8:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p125 :001 > d = File.read("./d3.js")
 => [...]
ruby-1.9.3-p125 :002 > d.encoding
 => #<Encoding:UTF-8> 
ruby-1.9.3-p125 :003 > d.valid_encoding?
 => true
```

**EDIT 2**:

I also tried to insert some voodoo in my `config/environment.rb`. It does not work:

```
# -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# --------- VOODOO BEGINS HERE -----------------
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
# --------- END VOODO --------------------------

# Initialize the rails application
Ratecode::Application.initialize!
```

Comment: Ever tried to check presence of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark ? Also try bisection: remove parts of the file to see, whether things would start working.

Comment: Can you also check the encoding of the application.js? The error says the two files are incompatible, you should check not only that the d3 file is UTF-8, but also that your application.js is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is the error from a WEBrick server or something else? Does `rake assets:precompile` work? (don't forget to clear the assets after)

If the latter fails, double check the value of your $LANG environment variables is UTF-8 (with `env`). If the rake task works but the app is failing then it could be the server env vars.

Comment: `rake assets:precompile` works flawlessly. The generated application.js contains the d3 library as expected. I removed the generated `public/assets` directory and restarted WEBrick. And now the error is just gone. I don't have any explanation.

Comment: I had a similar issue during development. Solved it with two lines: `RAILS_ENV=development rake assets:precompile` and then `RAILS_ENV=development rake assets:clean`

Comment: although it sounds completely silly to me, it works iblue and Yuri say. Any idea how compiling the assets and then removing them solve this issue?

Comment: I've had this happen a couple times, and just `RAILS_ENV=development rake assets:clean` and a server restart is enough to fix it. This most recent time, `public/assets` didn't even exist, so I have no idea how that fixed it.

Comment: not even using the asset full asset pipeline in development but Yuri's suggestion worked for me. Only explanation is that Rails asset pipeline is pretty insane and gets into a bad state from time to time. forcing encoding issues when in bad state? still seems weird