# Can't precomile sinatra assets via ansible

Tags: utf-8, sinatra, ansible, precompile, sinatra-assetpack

I am deploying my sinatra project via ansible, and one of the tasks is precompiling assets.

At first I stacked into question [how to initialize rbenv properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115936/install-bundler-gem-using-ansible).

Then, what I did is:

```
- name: Precompiling assets
  command: bash -lc "cd {{ build_path }} && bundle exec rake assetpack:build"
```

But then I got error `Encoding::UndefinedConversionError at assets/application.js`

When I connected by ssh to server and run `bundle exec rake assetpack:build` - everything worked perfectly.
So, I presumed, this is related to [setting environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525381/asset-pipeline-encoding-problems-utf-8-vs-ascii-8bit-with-external-gem)

`lookup('env', 'LANG')` says it is `"msg": "ru_RU.UTF-8"` but echo $LANG says it's "C" ([look there](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ansible-project/XwJmFPfMfo0)).

Look to [this issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/7060). It says:

> Ansible sets LANG to C on modules which don't need it

Ansible modules set "$LANG=C" automatically.

Adding environment variable *didn't give desired result*:

```
environment:
  LANG: ru_RU.UTF-8
command: bash -lc "cd {{ build_path }} && bundle exec rake assetpack:build"
```

At the same time shell module seem to know nothing about `bundle`, so *this didn't work* as well:

```
- name: Precompiling assets
  command: bash -lc "cd {{ build_path }} && bundle exec rake assetpack:build"
```

I tried huge bunch of commands, such as `export LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8`, `command` module, `shell` module, but nothing helps, all my attempts failed miserably.

I do not really know how to workaround this issue.

Need help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should've changed not only `LANG` variable, but both `LANG` and `LC_ALL`:

```
- name: Precompiling assets
  environment:
    LANG: "ru_RU.UTF-8"
    LC_ALL: "ru_RU.UTF-8"
  command: bash -lc "cd {{ build_path }} && bundle exec rake assetpack:build"
```

That worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

`command` module is not intended to be used with multiple shell commands. `shell` module should be used instead:

```
- name: Precompiling assets
  shell: bundle exec rake assetpack:build chdir={{ build_path }}
```

Any environment variable that is required before running `bundle` can be configured as in the next example:

```
- name: Precompiling assets
  shell: RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake assetpack:build chdir={{ build_path }}
```

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/shell_module.html

Comment: The question itself is not about difference between command and shell modules, it is about encoding problems I faced while compiling assets.

Comment: shell module does not know about `rake` or `bundle`